# Recursive addition for custom BigInteger class

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger

I am trying to implement my own BigInteger class where the BigInt is a List where each element is one digit in the number. I am trying to implement the plus() method to add two BigInts into eachother via recursion.

Although I am having troubles with my add() and am not sure how to implement the get methods for this case.

```
public BigInt plus(BigInt operand){
    List<Integer> a = this.getDigit();
    List<Integer> b = operand.getDigit();
    List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<>();

    if(a.size() > b.size()){
        sum = add(a,b,0,sum);
    } else {
        sum = add(b,a,0,sum);
    }
    return new BigInt(sum);
}

private List<Integer> add(List<Integer> x, List<Integer> y, final int carry, List<Integer> result){
    int sum;
    int c = carry;
    //if block is base case?
    if(y.size() == 1){
        sum = getSum(x,y,carry);
        c = getCarry(result, sum);

        if(sum>=10){
            sum = (x.get(x.size()-1) + c);
            x.remove(x.size()-1);
            x.add(sum);
        }
        for(int i = x.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){

            result.add(0,x.get(i));
        }
        return result;
    }

    //recursive case?
    sum = getSum(x,y,carry);
    c = getCarry(result,sum);

    return this.add(x,y,c,result);
}

public int getSum(List<Integer> x, List<Integer> y, final int carry){
    return 0;//PLACEHOLDER
}
public int getCarry(List<Integer> result, int sum){
    return 0;//PLACEHOLDER
}
```

and my constructors

```
private BigInt(List<Integer> b){
    this.digit = new ArrayList<>();
    this.digit.addAll(b);

}
private BigInt(String str){
    this.digit = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] s = str.split("");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s));
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        int b = Integer.valueOf(list.get(i));
        this.digit.add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?  This seems very complicated for implementing a "BigInteger" object.

Comment: @Jared is right. You are making this rather simple problem into something rather complicated. Do not call getThis and getThat. Simply use two loops: one for when the arrays overlap, and one for the rest of longer array. Just add together, say 9 + 7 = 16, so store 6 and carry 1. Next, say 3 + 8 (+1 for carry) = 12, so store 2 and carry 1, etc. The second loop only has to add the carry and establish the new carry, if any. What you are doing is way too convoluted and too complicated.

Comment: Thanks @RudyVelthuis I will test that out tonight. I think my lack of understanding with recursion is why I'm overcomplicating it (and implementing recursion here is the point of the project). The idea for the getSum and getCarry were to just modulate the code a bit more for readability.

Comment: Recursion, especially while modifying the original argument, is not the right tool here. You should not modify x or y at all. Just add x.get(i) to y.get(i) and store the result in result.set(i). The carry is maintained in the loop. I don't have enough time now, but I'll write up an answer later.

Comment: I'd appreciate that thank you. @RudyVelthuis

Comment: @Alkarin I'm afraid that will have to wait. Big family problems need all my attention. I can write short comments, but don't have time to sit down and write and test a solution, sorry. But if you can read Pascal, you can take a look at [my BigInteger implementation](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html). Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo. Try changing `int x = x.size()-1` to `int i = x.size()-1`.

Also, it's going to loop infinitely with `i++`. Did you mean `i--`?

Comment: Oh thank you, I feel like a dunce for not seeing either of those. edited post.